# Get primary key name in eloquent model

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

How to get name of primary key from model in laravel?

like this

```
dd(User::primaryKeyName()); // -> 'user_id'
```

I want to sort data on primary if 'order' is empty

```
$data = User::orderBy(Input::get('order', User::primaryKey()), 'ASC')->get();
```

but have

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getKeyName() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That method tries to get the value from a protected class property `return $this->primaryKey;` and `$this` needs a context from a class instance. If you really need to get that name dynamically, you could do this:

```
App::make('User')->getKeyName();
```

So your code would look something like this:

```
$data = User::orderBy(Input::get('order', App::make('User')->getKeyName()), 'ASC')->get();
```

Answer (score 10):

The fastest way to do this is probably like so:

```
(new User)->getKeyName();
(new User)->getTable();
```

However, I think the two approaches below provide a cleaner interface to the method.

The first approach uses a static method on your base model class:

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    protected static function KeyName() {
        return (new static)->getKeyName();
    }

    protected static function TableName() {
        return (new static)->getTable();
    }
}
```

Then inherit from this class in your model:

```
class ModelName extends BaseModel
{
    ...
}
```

And use like this: `ModelName::KeyName();`

If you don't have access to a base model class you can also use a trait:

```
trait EloquentGetTableNameTrait
{
    public static function TableName()
    {
        return (new static)->getTable();
    }
}
```

Which you use like this in your model:

```
class ModelName
{
    use EloquentGetTableNameTrait;

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, all these approaches require instantiating an instance of the model, but there is currently no other way to retrieve this value.

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436

Comment: +1 For a valid approach. The issue you referenced also contains some other nice solutions such as chaining the method call when creating the instance `(new User)->getTable()`, which is just as readable as `User::tableName()` and is essentially the same, so you might want to include that in your answer as well.

Comment: I know about this way, it's all good, but one thing is bad: you should change code of application, if you want to use this as module. In case you make admin interface, that can select/search/delete/create rows, you want to just copy and paste code from one project to another, and this code should work without any changes in model.

Comment: @KoIIIeY If you want to extend the core functionality of Eloquent models then you need to use either inheritance as showcased in this answer, define a trait that implements these methods and include that (probably the most flexible option here) or possibly use a decorator class (which would be overkill for this). Either way you need some extra code on top of Laravel's codebase. And if you just want to _copy and paste_ code to another project, what's stopping you to copy the extra code needed for this to work with the models?

Comment: @Bogdan, 2 years ago your answer helped me. One of many reasons, to not use trait or something else is that I dont know, what models we have (and names of models too). So, model itself is the black box for programmer. Question closed, thanks :)